# Debezium failed - Cannot replicate because the master purged required binary logs

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, amazon-rds, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using debezium-kafka to capture changes in MySQL. For MySQL I'm using AWS RDS.
I've a read-replica configuration with GTID enabled. I've connected debezium with the replica.

But after running few days, debezium failed with error :

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Cannot replicate because the master purged required binary logs. Replicate the missing transactions from elsewhere, or provision a new slave from backup. Consider increasing the master's binary log expiration period. To find the missing transactions, see the master's error log or the manual for GTID_SUBTRACT. Error code: 1236; SQLSTATE: HY000.
tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:230)
tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:197)
tat io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader$ReaderThreadLifecycleListener.onCommunicationFailure(BinlogReader.java:1018)
tat com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:950)
tat com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:580)
tat com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:825)
tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
aused by: com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.network.ServerException: Cannot replicate because the master purged required binary logs. Replicate the missing transactions from elsewhere, or provision a new slave from backup. Consider increasing the master's binary log expiration period. To find the missing transactions, see the master's error log or the manual for GTID_SUBTRACT.
tat com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:914)
t... 3 more
```

I'm unable to figure out what is causing issue, both MYSQL master and replica are healthy, both are up and running. Then why debezium failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution, I am using Amazon RDS MySQL. Amazon RDS normally purges a binary log as soon as possible. Due to which GTID was getting purged before getting consumed by Debezium.

To specify the number of hours for RDS to retain binary:

```
call mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 24);
```

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html